# Detect check-box change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of check box items.

```
<ul class="level_1 ">
    <li class="level_1"><input type="checkbox" name="Settings"
        class="Settings" value="1"><label> Text 1</label></li>
    <li class="level_1"><input type="checkbox" name="Settings"
        class="Settings" value="2"><label> Text 2</label></li>
    <li class="level_1"><input type="checkbox" name="Settings"
        class="Settings" value="3"><label> Text 3</label></li>
</ul>

<div class="buttons">
    <input Value="Save" type="submit" id="settings_save_button"
        class="save yellow" name="settings_save_button"
        onclick="return false;" value="" />
</div>

bindData: function() {
    var self = this;
    $("#settings_save_button").click(function() {
        self.updateSettings();
    });
};

updateSettings: function () {
            var self = this;
            var ele = self.element;
            var formData = $(ele).find('form#edit_settings_form');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: formData.attr("action"),
                data: formData.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    var userInfo = eval(data);
                    self.userRepo.updateUser(userInfo);
                    alert("saved");
                },
                error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (req.status == Portal.Constants.AJAX_VALIDATION_ERROR_CODE) {
                        self.addErrorMessageAndShowThem(eval("(" + req.responseText + ")"));
                    }
                },
                datatype: "json"
            });
        }
```

I now want to get rid of this save button. Instead I want the submit event to fire, every time user selects a new checkbox value. How can I bind the change in any checkbox with updateSettings method instead of click event of save button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change) of the input element to bind a handler which will be called when the checkbox's checked state is changed

```
var self = this;
$('input[name="Settings"]').change(function () {
    self.updateSettings();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. this works fine as far as calling updateSettings method is concerned. But my data is not getting updated with ajax call. It gets updated with save button, but not with checkbox change. I have updated the question.

Comment: Instead of getting 'Settings=1' as formData on selecting first checkbox I am getting 'Settings=1&Settings=4' which is both old and new value. That's why values are not updating.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind that event to your check box

like this :

```
$(".Settings").on('change',function(e){
    e.updateSettings();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
$('input[name="Settings"]').bind('click',function(){

   //your code goes here
});
```

OR

```
$('input[name="Settings"]').on('click',function(){

   //your code goes here
   return true;
});
```

Cheers